# Error: param is missing or the value is empty: thing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, parameters, actioncontroller

I'm using rails 4.0.8. I added a comment section to a model called 'Things', but I keep getting the same error "param is missing or the value is empty: thing" when I press the submit comment button. It says the error is in the Things#Controller. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: I removed the url path from the form, but a new error returns "Couldn't find Thing without an ID". The error is in Comments#Controller.

VIEW FOR THING/SHOW

```
<div id= "thing">
  <h1>
    <%= @thing.name %>
  </h1>
  <br>
  <div id= "commentsection">
    Comments
    <div id= "comments">
      <br>
      <% @thing.comments.each do |c| %>
        <%= c.username %>
        <br>
        <%= c.text %>
      <% end %>
      <%= form_for @comment, :url => thing_path do |f| %>

        <%= f.label :username %>
        <%= f.text_field :username %>

        <%= f.label :comment %>
        <%= f.text_field :text %>

        <%= f.submit "Enter", class: "btn btn-small btn-primary" %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

THINGS CONTROLLER

```
class ThingsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @thing = Thing.find(params[:id])
    @thing.comments.build
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  def index
  end

  def new
    @thing = Thing.new
    @things = Thing.all
  end

  def create
    @thing = Thing.new(thing_params)
    if @thing.save
      redirect_to @thing
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private
    def thing_params
      params.require(:thing).permit(:name, :avatar)
    end

end
```

COMMENTS CONTROLLER (I put asterisks around the line where the error is)

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @comment = Comment.new
    @comments = Comment.all
  end

  def create
    ****@thing = Thing.find(params[:thing_id])****
    @comment = @thing.comments.create(comment_params)
    redirect_to thing_path(@thing)
    end
  end

  private

    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:user, :text, :upvotes, :downvotes, :thing_id)
    end

end
```

ROUTES

```
Website::Application.routes.draw do

  get "comments/new"
  get "comments/show"
  get "things/new"
  root 'home_page#home'
  get "all/things/new" => 'things#new'
  get "all/allthings"
  resources :things
    resources :good_comments
  get "things/show"
  get "things/results"

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are posting the `@comment` form to `post '/things' path`.

```
<%= form_for @comment, :url => thing_path do |f| %>
```

It should just be `<%= form_for @comment do %>` (Rails is smart enough to plug in the comments_path) or if you feel like being more explicit (even though it's not necessary)

```
<%= form_for @comment, url: :comments_path do %>
```

Another note though, if you want that `Comment` to be tied to that specific `Thing` then in your models it should be

```
Class Thing
  has_many :comments
end

Class Comment
  belongs_to :thing
end
```

Then make sure in your database `comment` has a `thing_id foreign_key field` and then your form for comment should actually look like

`<%= form_for @thing, @comment do %> 
<% end %>`

Comment: Thanks! I removed the pointless url path, but now I have a new error in Comments#Controller, "Couldn't find Thing without an ID". Any idea why that might be? My models are set up correctly and each comment has a thing_id.

Comment: @user3739453 Your form has to be `<%= form_for @thing, @comment do %>` In your `Comment Controller` you are asking for `params[:thing_id]` but the url your form is currently generating if you inspect it is `/comments`. It needs to be `'/thing/:thing_id/comments'` which also means you need to adjust your routes to include `resources :things do resources :comments end`

Comment: Okay, now it gives me "can't write unknown attribute 'html'" and highlights the line `<%= form_for @thing, @comment do |f| %>`.

Comment: @user3739453 `<%= form_for [@thing,@comment] do %>` ***

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works! I'd vote your answer up but I don't have enough reputation :/

Comment: That's okay. I'd recommending reading the Rails docs more thoroughly, Rails is awesome because troubleshooting becomes fairly easy once you're familiar with the structure! http://rubyonrails.org/documentation/